# link CSS file to Haml layout Template

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to link `css` file to `haml` layout template

I have method in `ApplicationHelper` to generate proper `html`

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def styletag(sheet_name)
    "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/stylesheets/#{sheet_name}.css'>"
  end

end
```

and also link to layout template

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Rotten Potatoes!
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = styletag 'default'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

but it seems like `haml` doesn't consider it like a tag and it's displayed like a text.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Rails already has a helper for this, it's right there above the line you're reference: `stylesheet_link_tag`. You **really** shouldn't write your own helper for this, the asset pipeline is more complex than you seem to realize, and your helper will wind up failing in weird ways.

Comment: Despite my answer below if that's really all you need to do you should use stylesheet_link_tag as @meagar states.  Especially since it will work with the asset pipeline properly

Comment: @meagar you are right but i have a problem if i use 'stylesheet_link_tag' path is incorrect and 404 not found is returned , even thought file is in correct folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add html_safe. Rails by default is escaping the html in your text so you need to tell rails that it should not do so.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag and click "Show Source"
If you change it to this:

```
def styletag(sheet_name)
    "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/stylesheets/#{sheet_name}.css'>".html_safe
end
```

it should work for you